# Add extra status to wordpress gravityview plugin for gravityforms

Tags: php, gravityforms

In gravityview wordpress plugin of gravityroms i need to add to the core an extra status... until today gravityview only work with 3 diferent status for approval system

- GravityView_Entry_Approval_Status::APPROVED - Approved/Accepted entries
- GravityView_Entry_Approval_Status::DISAPPROVED - Disapproved/Rejected entries
- GravityView_Entry_Approval_Status::UNAPPROVED - Unapproved/Not Reviewed entries

So.. I need to add other status called EDITED because I need that when the entry is edited it changes to this status and next filter the entries that match this status

Does anyone know any way to do this? maybe some code snippet...

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

The only possible way of achieving this is to use the gravityview approve/reject field in the form editor (Not the view) and then manually add options like you would with a normal dropdown:

[image]

https://docs.gravityview.co/article/584-can-i-add-an-additional-status-to-the-approval-system